# Winforms Disabling Control Box from showing up

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a Winforms application without any `Toolbars`. The main window has `FormBorderStyle` set to `Sizable` and `ControlBox` is set to `true`. Every time I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then use <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> (not <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>) the control box shows up on the top left hand side of my application. This is annoying because there are shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> available in my grid, and if the user just presses and releases <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then <kbd>Up</kbd> to go to previous row the control box shows up.

How can I override this?

Comment: Windows shortcut standards dictate that the modifier and shortcut key must be pressed at the same time.  What you want to do goes against this standard.

Comment: No. I am not trying to go against any standard. Pressing and releasing just the "Alt" modifier is causing the problem here. Other hotkeys say like Alt+R, or Alt+J works fine. I don't want anything to happen just by pressing and releasing Alt.

Comment: I just created a brand new Winforms app with nothing on it.
When I press just Alt, and then followed by up or Down arrow key (not Alt+Up or Alt+Down) I see the control box. It seems to be a default Windows behavior. I can't disable this unless I set the ControlBox to false, which I don't want to do.

I don't know, may be I am missing something basic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ken: I tried your code and focus was still going to `ControlBox` for some reason.
Tweaked it a bit and it worked perfectly for my needs.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{ 
    if (keyData == (Keys.RButton | Keys.ShiftKey | Keys.Alt))
    { return true; }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting [`ShowIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showicon.aspx) to `false`?

Comment: Yes. It is set to false, but that does not prevent the control box from appearing.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Alt)
    {
        keyData = Keys.None;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```